# PGP for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, pgp

What is the best/simpliest to use PGP library for use with an ASP.NET application?

We need to be able to encrypt a text file for submission to a vendor via FTP.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787398/pgp-library-for-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/sharpprivacy.aspx?df=100&forumid=15716&exp=0&select=573797 and http://www.bouncycastle.org/index.html

Edit: I'd go for bouncy castle's api.

Comment: Thanks.  
Has anyone used OpenPGP Library for .NET from DidiSoft?  It seems like it wraps the core bouncycastle calls to simplify things but curious if it has any issues sicne it is $400